# My image assets fail to load for a nib in my iOS app

Tags: ios, uikit, interface-builder

My image assets fail to load for a nib in my iOS app, but I have added them with interface builder's dropdown that lists my files.

I get an error message saying that it failed to load "Foo.png", but I can see this in my bundle, and Interface Builder populates its drop down selection box for the image with "Foo.png" as well.

Foo.png is in a subfolder in the bundle called "Textures"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode seems to go out of its way to hide paths and stop you from needing to specify them fully. However, this can cause confusion for both the developer and the tools themselves.

Specifically, in Interface Builder you need to fully qualify the path relative to the bundle root. If you do not do this then the asset will fail to load along with any @2x, @3x versions of it you may have placed next to it. This means that Interface Builder will show you a broken image when you specify the path correctly, however the image will show on device and in the simulator when running the app.

This bug has been present in all versions of Xcode I have used from 3.x through to 6.2. Hopefully it is fixed in a future version. I believe I have reported these long ago, I would highly recommend every developer who uses these features to report these bugs to Apple too.

Note that due to another long standing set of Xcode bugs it is necessary to delete the bundle from the device and do a clean build to ensure that this change has any effect when running the app to test if it fixes the issue.